# How to test if an array contains a pair of numbers whose product is odd?

Tags: java, algorithm, integer

How can I write a function that takes an array of integers and returns true if their exists a pair of numbers whose product is odd?

What are the properties of odd integers? And of course, how do you write this function in Java? Also, maybe a short explanation of how you went about formulating an algorithm for the actual implementation.

Yes, this is a function out of a textbook. No, this is not homework—I'm just trying to learn, so please no "do your own homework comments."

Comment: maybe we can tag such questions as "task" too?

Comment: Maybe tag them "learning" in place of "homework"?

Comment: yeah, that's a nice idea. "task" could be confused with "homework". "learning" is not so ambiguous

Comment: replaced "function" tag with "learning"

Comment: If I was trying to get help with my homework I'd make sure to say I wasn't trying to get help with my homework...

Answer (score 15):

An odd number is not evenly divisible by two.  All you need to know is are there two odd numbers in the set.  Just check to see if each number mod 2 is non-zero.  If so it is odd.  If you find two odd numbers then you can multiply those and get another odd number.

Note: an odd number multiplied by an even number is always even.

Answer (score 6):

The product of two integers will be odd *only* if both integers are odd.  So, to solve this problem, just scan the array once and see if there are two (or more) odd integers.

**EDIT:**  As others have mentioned, you check to see if a number is odd by using the modulus (%) operator.  If N % 2 == 0, then the number is even.

Comment: 7 + 3 = 10.  I think you meant the product of two integers is even only if both integers are odd.

Comment: The product is the result of multiplication.  The sum is the result of addition.

Answer (score 3):

Properties worth thinking about:

- Odd numbers are not divisible by 2
- Any number multiplied by an even number is even

So you can re-state the question as:

> Does the array contain at least two integers that are not divisible by 2?

Which should make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for evenness (or oddness) by using the modulus.

i % 2 = 0 if i is even; test for that and you can find out if a number is even/odd

Answer (score 0):

A brute force algorithm:

```
public static boolean hasAtLeastTwoOdds(int[] args) {
    int[] target = args; // make defensive copy
    int oddsFound;
    int numberOddsSought = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        if (target[i] % 2 != 0) {
            if (oddsFound== numberOddsSought) {
                return true;
            }
            oddsFound++;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: We're looking for odd numbers, not even ones.

Comment: You don't initialize oddsFound.  And, you're incrementing oddsFound AFTER doing the test? Ummm... your code has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers and comments.

I now understand well how to test whether an integer is odd. For example, this method is a neat way of doing this test without using multiplication, modulus, or division operators:

```
 protected boolean isOdd(int i) {
    return ( (i&1) == 1);

}
```

With your help, I now realize that the problem is much simpler than I had expected. Here is the rest of my implementation in Java. Comments and criticism are welcome.

```
protected boolean isOddProduct(int[] arr) {
        int oddCount = 0;
        if (arr.length < 2) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (isOdd(arr[i]))
                oddCount++; 
        }
        return oddCount > 1;
    }
```

I wonder if there exists any other ways to perform this test without using *, % or / operators? Maybe I'll ask this question in a new thread.

Comment: the last if statement is unnecessary, just return oddCount > 1; (this is a big pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Also, you could write the isOdd function simply as "return (i & 1) == 1;" - no need for the return true/false statements as you already have a Boolean value from the test.

Comment: Thank you mmattax and Greg for your comments--I went back and fixed this .